# How to run method in object - beginner

Tags: eclipse, scala

I'm attempting to learn Scala coming from a Java background. Should the below program run ? When I right click on the file `Functional` an option to run the file is not displayed. What do I need to change to run the method `Timer.run`?
I'm using the Eclipse3.7 & Scala plugin 2.0.2.

```
class Functional {

  object Timer {
    def oncePerSecond(callback: () => Unit) {
      while (true) { callback(); Thread sleep 1000 }
    }
    def timeFlies() {
      println("time flies like an arrow...")
    }
    def run() {
      oncePerSecond(timeFlies)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Timer.run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main method should reside on an `object` definition, not in `class`. The methods that are defined in an `object` are somewhat equivalent to `static` ones from Java.

Comment: In addition I have to say that it is much much easier to use `App` trait (mix it to your object) instead of writing main method, just like in Getting Started section of [Scala for Java refugees](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-1).

Comment: @om-nom-nom +1 great introduction within that tutorial, thanks